# I am unable to open file with \Template::instance()->render. I am getting the following error

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

It is giving me the following error,

[text] => Unable to open /home/mehul/www/portal.hsua.com.au/public_html/assets/templates.html

This is the part of code which is causing the problem.

```
    $this->f3->set('const', $constants);
    ob_start();
    echo \Template::instance()->render('/home/mehul/www/portal.hsua.com.au/public_html/assets/templates.html');
    $renderedView = ob_get_clean();

    /*foreach ($variables as $varname => $variable) {
        $this->f3->clear($varname);
    }*/

    return $renderedView;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The file might not exist
2. you're opening the PHP file in your webbrowser PHP file is somewhere located in /var/www delivered by Nginx / Apache. If that's the case, your webserver probably has no access to open a file within your home directory.

I recommend you put the template files next to your PHP file to make sure your webserver has access to it.

Answer (score 0):

The `render()` methods concatenates the given template `$file` with all template paths stored in the `UI` system variable while searching for a valid file. Therefore you either have to specify a relative path or append `/` as workaround.

**Workaround**

```
$f3 = Base::instance();
$f3->concat('UI', ';/');
```

**Source/Reference**

The concatination `$dir.$file` in [base.php#L2791](https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree-core/blob/6fe3128ffe0940972c1d292751fb3bb3a0c25c2e/base.php#L2791)  is the culprit. Your error is generated a few lines below.

**Update / Example**

```
$f3 = Base::instance();
$f3->concat('UI', ';/'); // Add support for absolute paths.

echo \Template::instance()
    ->render(__DIR__ . '/template.html');
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Actually, I am new in this filed. Could you tell me where I have to modify the code.

Comment: I tested and updated my answer. You have to add `/` to support absolute paths. An empty string is not sufficient. I also took the time to have a second look at your code and had to raise a brow because of your ob_start() usage. You don't need explicit output buffering except you want to prevent rendering broken templates when the template is able to throw exceptions (e.g. when letting PHP throw exceptions instead of only creating `NOTICE` information). `Template->render()` returns a string with the rendered content.