# 500 error when an unset framework variable is used in template

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

I got a mysterious error on the page routed to MainController::somefunction

```
Internal Server Error
Unable to open

[vendor/bcosca/fatfree/lib/base.php:2315] Base->error()
[vendor/bcosca/fatfree/lib/base.php:3130] user_error()
[tmp/1esys3p2sx9xp.3h31n1yj254w8.php:2] Preview->render()
[vendor/bcosca/fatfree/lib/base.php:2875] require('/opt/lampp/htdocs/project/tmp/1esys3p2sx9xp.3h31n1yj254w8.php')
[vendor/bcosca/fatfree/lib/base.php:3121] View->sandbox()
[app/controllers/MainController.php:41] Preview->render()
[vendor/bcosca/fatfree/lib/base.php:1928] MainController->somefunction()
[vendor/bcosca/fatfree/lib/base.php:1728] Base->call()
[index.php:12] Base->run()
```

In my MainController::somefunction() a variable is set to a template

```
$this->f3->set('content', 'products.htm');
echo \Template::instance()->render('layout.htm');
```

And in layout.htm has the following line

```
    <include href="{{ @contents }}" />
```

The error message did not provide much useful detail. It took me a while to find out that the variable is defined as 'content' in the function but the template referenced 'contents' -- there is a missed 's'.

It would be more helpful if the error could say sth like "undefined variable". Maybe this information will find someone scratching their head.

Comment: This feels similar to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50481507/i-am-unable-to-open-file-with-templateinstance-render-i-am-getting-the-fo

Answer (score 1):

The primary issue is that your PHP configuration is ignoring "minor issues" like undefined variables. Let PHP report all kinds of issues by calling `error_reporting(E_ALL)` (after loading F3). Technically, `E_NOTICE` is enough to report undefined variables. As soon as this flag is set, PHP can show/log (depends on your configuration) a warning and Fat-Free Framework's `ONERROR` handler can react to undefined variables

```
Undefined variable: contents
[tmp/21hg1fh3jezo8.1gkglltf97qxb.php:1] Base->{closure}()
[test.php:16] Preview->render()
```

I recommend to promote warnings to exceptions, too. A good example is shown in a comment of the [documentation page of `set_error_handler()`](https://www.php.net/function.set-error-handler#112881). This change forces you to program defensively and reveals issue that otherwise would go either unnoticed or result in unexpected side-effects (like your issue).

Feel free to create a pull request against [bcosca/fatfree-core](https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree-core) that generates a helpful error message when a `null` file is passed to the template renderer.

Answer (score 0):

@Alan T, @alan-t ,  right ; just starting with F3 this week i scratched my head 2 days ago with this same issue ; my 2 cents : when something like thing happens, whatever framework or library you are using, proceed with a file search project wide ; for instance in your case you can do a search for "Unable to open" to see where exactly it bugs , and i've been lucky to find the culprid line thanks to the trace with the exact line number displayed.(not the case in your issue/stact trace)

BIG Thanks to @Rayne for all this precious info regarding 'calling error_reporting(E_ALL) after loading F3'
and especially regarding promoting warnings to exceptions; i'm going to update my code base right after this reply

Thanks all to help beginners with what seems to me so far a very efficient packed framework! And the official doc is full of clever code samples when we take time to dig into it! Thanks to all f3 folks

Best regards
Raphael